# Jest: toHaveBeenCalled returning 0 instead of 1

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function called liquidation tracker that does something along the lines of:

```js
// liquidation_tracker.js file
async function liquidation_tracker(sendSms) {
  const requires_notification = [1,2,3] // some dummy data
  if (requires_notification.length > 0 && sendSms) {
        sendNotification(requires_notification)
    }
}

async function sendNotification() {
  return null // assume it sends an sms
}
```

The test code I've tried to do is

```js
const liquidation_tracker = require('./liquidation_tracker);
liquidation_tracker.sendNotification = jest.fn();
it('should notify if margin ratio is > 0.8', async () => {
    const check = await liquidation_tracker.checkLiquidation(true);
    expect(liquidation_tracker.sendNotification).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

But this is returning a 0 instead of a 1

Comment: `sendNotification` is not a property of `liquidation_tracker` in the code you're showing. Either your example is not reflective, or it *is*, in which case you cannot access `sendNotification` as a property. You need the actual function reference.

Comment: Sorry just edited it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the mocked `sendNotification` function has the same reference with the `sendNotification` function called inside the `checkLiquidation` function.

E.g.

`liquidation_tracker.js`:

```js
async function checkLiquidation(sendSms) {
  const requires_notification = [1, 2, 3];
  if (requires_notification.length > 0 && sendSms) {
    exports.sendNotification(requires_notification);
  }
}

async function sendNotification() {
  return null;
}

exports.checkLiquidation = checkLiquidation;
exports.sendNotification = sendNotification;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const liquidation_tracker = require('./liquidation_tracker');

describe('61657292', () => {
  it('should notify if margin ratio is > 0.8', async () => {
    const sendNotificationMock = jest.fn();
    liquidation_tracker.sendNotification = sendNotificationMock;
    await liquidation_tracker.checkLiquidation(true);
    expect(sendNotificationMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61657292/liquidation_tracker.test.js (12.385s)
  61657292
    ✓ should notify if margin ratio is > 0.8 (4ms)

------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                    | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files               |   83.33 |       75 |      50 |   83.33 |                   
 liquidation_tracker.js |   83.33 |       75 |      50 |   83.33 | 9                 
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.201s
```

Comment: That's super odd. I can't seem to replicate it and it still keeps running. For some reason the mock itself doesn't override the sendNotification function and that keeps running as per normal? Any thoughts?

The only different I can see is that I am using a `module.exports = {sendNotification, checkLiquidation}` at the top of my file and I don't call `exports.sendNotification()`. Even when I did try with that syntax I am still having called 0, expected 1

Comment: I actually managed to get it to work but no idea what difference it made. I removed the sendNotification function from the liquidation_tracker file and moved it to a different one and then it worked...